# Unable to configure tensorflow to use GPU acceleration in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install Tensorflow in Ubuntu 16.04 ( in google cloud ). What I have done so far is created an compute instance. I have added a NVIDIA Tesla K80 to this instance.

[image]

Also, made sure that the proper version of tensorflow ( version 1.14.0 ) is installed and

Cuda version of 8.0 is installed
and 
CudNN version of 6.0 is installed as per the tensorflow gpu - cuda mapping

When I run a simple tensorflow program, I get

Cannot assign a device for operation MatMul: {{node MatMul}}was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, **/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0** ]. **Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device**.

Can anyone please let me know where I am doing wrong. Is the instance selection is correct?

Please do let me know and thanks for your help.

Comment: Although highly unlikely, you've installed tensorflow-gpu right? Moreover, you could configure your session like this : `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0}))`

Comment: @E.N.D - Yes. I have installed tensorflow-gpu

Comment: The CUDA and CudNN versions that have been tested with Tensorflow 1.14 are the 10.0 and the 7.4, respectively. That information can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). Could you please check whether using those versions solves the issue?

Comment: @DanielDuato - Thanks for your comment. This is the perfect answer. Tensorflow GPU is working fine with  Cuda 10.0 and the Cudnn 7.4

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I'll repost my comment as an answer to increase its visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CUDA and CudNN versions that have been tested with Tensorflow 1.14 are the 10.0 and the 7.4, respectively.

More information about version compatibility can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).